# Is the Qt Eclipse integration plugin still available for download?

Tags: eclipse, qt, eclipse-plugin

I want to start developing a new C++ application with Qt in the Eclipse IDE. I read about a Qt integration plugin from Nokia but can not find it to download, nor any official statement whether it is been discontinued or renamed.

Is there still a Qt GUI plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: Qt is supported by new versions of Eclipse CDT

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Work was stopped on it a long time ago, and when Qt became open-source it had become so out of date it was removed from the downloads page.  The Windows version is still available at [Softpedia](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Qt-Eclipse-Integration.shtml) though.

I must say, if I were you, I would use Qt Creator.  Development on it has accelerated in the last couple of years and it is much better than Eclipse for Qt work (I actually prefer it for general C++ work as well).

Comment: I am currently testing Qt-Creator and like it very much. The only thing I miss are those automatic code generation features of eclipse that automatically generate function stubs if you call an inexistent function.

Comment: I'll second the comment above. Eclipse is slow, memory hungry and has terrible UI.  It's the jack-of-all-trades and master of none.

Comment: The ftp link is broken. Seems like is not going to be distributed anymore.

Comment: What a shame, no one seems to host the integration package

Comment: Look here:  ftp://ftp.informatik.hu-berlin.de/pub/Linux/Qt/QT/qteclipse/