# Develop a Qt applications using Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, eclipse-plugin, qt-creator

i have a question for you..really this is't a question..is a simple advice..

I developed my logic application using c++ and Eclipse.

Now I must to develop the UI.

I would like to use Qt for this component.

So, I have to try to import my external library and my code into Qt creator..but I have some problems during the configuration project to compile.

Can I use Eclipse with Qt plugin? In this way, have I the graphic UI editor?

There will be special problems if I will use Eclipse instead of QtCreator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618223/is-the-qt-eclipse-integration-plugin-still-available-for-download

Comment: Have you considered keeping the logic in Eclipse as a separate project, and using that project as a library in your UI project developed in Qt Creator?