# Qt eclipse integration for c++

Tags: eclipse, qt

where i can find an available link to download Qt for eclipse because [this one](http://qt.nokia.com/developer/eclipse-integration/) is not available anymore and all references from google are to that link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very similar question: [Is the Qt Eclipse integration plugin still available for download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618223/is-the-qt-eclipse-integration-plugin-still-available-for-download)

Short answer:

- You should use QtCreator instead, because the Qt Eclipse integration is outdated
- There's a link in that question's comments where you can still download the Qt Eclipse files

Comment: That link is still outdated :D