# How to connect Qt libraries to standard C++ project?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gcc

I work on Linux Mint and I've created standard C++ project in Eclipse IDE. I'd like to write some GUI application using Qt library but I don't quite know how to attach the library.

For GCC C++ Compiler there are flags:
-I (paths with header files to be included, if I understand correctly, the compiler will look in these directories when searching header files specified by -include flag)
-include (the actual header files)

For GCC C++ Linker:
-l (libraries, e.g *.so libraries)
-L (library search paths, the linker will look in these directories when searching libraries specified by -l flag)

Is this correct?

Now...

```
/usr/lib $ ls | grep qt
The output is:
libindicate-qt.so.1
libindicate-qt.so.1.4.1
libntrack-qt4.so.1
libntrack-qt4.so.1.0.1
libpolkit-qt-agent-1.so.1
libpolkit-qt-agent-1.so.1.103.0
libpolkit-qt-core-1.so.1
libpolkit-qt-core-1.so.1.103.0
libpolkit-qt-gui-1.so.1
libpolkit-qt-gui-1.so.1.103.0
libsignon-qt5.so.1
libsignon-qt5.so.1.0
libsignon-qt5.so.1.0.0
libsignon-qt.so.1
libsignon-qt.so.1.0
libsignon-qt.so.1.0.0
libsvnqt.so.7
libsvnqt.so.7.0.1
```

and in directory /usr/include/qt5 there are multiple other directories, each one with some number of header files, e.g:

```
/usr/include/qt5/QtConcurrent $ ls
QtConcurrent                qtconcurrentfilter.h            QtConcurrentMap             QtConcurrentRun                   QtConcurrentVersion
qtconcurrentcompilertest.h  qtconcurrentfilterkernel.h      qtconcurrentmap.h           qtconcurrentrunbase.h             qtconcurrentversion.h
QtConcurrentDepends         qtconcurrentfunctionwrappers.h  qtconcurrentmapkernel.h     qtconcurrentrun.h
qtconcurrentexception.h     qtconcurrent_global.h           qtconcurrentmedian.h        qtconcurrentstoredfunctioncall.h
QtConcurrentFilter          qtconcurrentiteratekernel.h     qtconcurrentreducekernel.h  qtconcurrentthreadengine.h
```

My question is how to include there headers and libraries. I'd like to include all headers below /usr/include/qt5/ and all Qt libraries from /usr/lib.

In other words.. what string should follow each of flags:
-I, -include, -l, -L ?

Thanks in advance. Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: You could configure Eclipse for usage with cmake. And then you can use Qt with cmake. This not as easy as using qmake, but it works. There even is some [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html) from Qt about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling a Qt project requires running the [preprocessor `moc`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/moc.html) to translate all Qt signals/slots. This preprocessor can be run either by `qmake` or by `cmake`. Since [Qt no longer maintains a plugin for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395872/qt-eclipse-integration-for-c), if you really want to use Eclipse, you need to configure Eclipse for using cmake, and then configuring cmake for invoking moc. MalaKa already provided you a [link about some documentation from Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html).

However, if you are going to develop with Qt, I strongly encourage you to drop Eclipse in favor of [Qt Creator](http://www.qt.io/ide/), which is a wonderful IDE and has the built-in mechanism for invoking qmake.

Comment: qmake is not at all *necessary* to build Qt code. There are other tools, such as CMake, that can cope with Qt's preprocessing steps just fine.

Comment: I meant `moc`. I've refined the answer. Thank you for pointing out.